# Check if vim is opened in tty

Tags: terminal, colorscheme

Normally I'm using the light theme in vim but if I open vim in the tty with the `background=light` option, than I can't see anything (almost everything is white). So I'd like to set `background=dark` automatically if I open vim in the tty.

What's the best way to check in vim (with vimscript) if vim is opened in the tty?

Comment: Do you mean "in the tty" as opposed to what... As opposed to using the GUI version of Vim (`gvim`)? Or do you mean something else (like using `vim` or `ex` in some kind of batch mode)?

Comment: I mean the virtual terminal if you don't run the Xorg server on linux: https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-tty-command/

Comment: either use a shell script, that acts depending on the output of `tty`, or use an if condition depending on the `$TERM` environment variable (for a plain tty, this should be `linux`, else most likely something like `xterm`). Ah, I see @Rich has just used that in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you mean, but for me, when I'm running in the [Linux console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console), `$TERM` is set to `linux`, and when I'm running in a terminal emulator it's set to e.g. `xterm`. (In GUI Vim it's entirely empty.)

So:

```
if $TERM == 'linux'
  set background=dark
endif
```